# Netbeans compiles fine but show errors in editor

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, classpath

Netbeans is not importing a jar from another project. The classpath is fine, the project compiles fine but the editor show several errors in project because it cannot locate classes inside that jar. I've already rebuilded the projects and clean Netbeans' cache (~/.netbeans/7.1.1/var/cache/)

Netbeans version: 7.1.1 and also 7.0

OS version: MacOS 10.7.3

The problem lies with the Netbeans' code editor. My project compiles and it's packaged just fine. I have no problem on that. I have this annoying error messages (eg. red background) in the code editor with no reason.

---

**A workaround I just found:** Renaming the dependency project (with refactoring) and adding the new jar to my project do the trick. Still I don't know what happened.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I just had the similar issue.  Using Windows 10 with NetBeans 8.2, the editor showed an error, but it compiled/ran fine.  Just restarting NetBeans cleared up the issue for me the "errors" in the editor.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem in NetBeans 7.2.1 today.  I could build the project fine but got error markers in the source files and in the Projects tree listings.  It seems as if the compiler when you build a project uses a different classpath from the compiler that works in the edit window.

In my case I found we had the same package and class names for different classes in different jars.  I don't know if this is relevant or just a red herring.

I still had an error in one project that used these two jars.  It seemed like it could only see the classes from the second jar listed in the pom.xml file (we use Maven).  I commented out the second jar & rebuilt, then uncommented that second jar & rebuilt and suddenly all of my errors went away.

So I don't have a definite solution but removing and reintroducing a dependency worked for me.

Comment: I, too, have the same package and class names for different classes in different jars.

Answer (score 0):

How you import jar file ? You have to right click Libralies in Project Panel and click Add JAR/Folder. And select jar file which you want to import.

Comment: I know how to import a jar. The jar is imported. That's not my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have wrongly imported the jar file. Try out the below steps to add jar(s) to your classpath properly.

```
1. Select your project from the Projects explorer.
2. Right click -> Properties.
3. Select Libraries from Categories list.
4. Click on Add JAR/Folder button.
5. Add your jar(s) & click on OK to finish the process.
```

Now, it should resolve the reference issues

Comment: That's what I did. I do this all the time, I think it's a Netbeans bug. I was looking for people with similar issue or a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned, the editor shows errors because it cannot locate classes inside that jar. Well, are you sure you are using the right jar or right version of jar ? Eclipse is not able to locate any of the classes or only few classes ?

Comment: It's not Eclipse, It's Netbeans and It's not able to locate any of the classes in my jar. The jar is another project of mine.

Comment: If you are referring to another project, then right click on the libraries node in the project explorer, select *Add project*, select your other project.

Comment: It's only a jar. I've done both, adding only that jar to my project or adding the whole project as a dependency. Neither of those works.

Answer (score 0):

I wish my answer would help fixing the issue (even if too late :) )
Indeed, I have a maven project with two modules. Module1 that contains the class com.x.y.MyClass and Module2 where I'm trying to import com.x.y.MyClass.
It compiles fine, and I can run unit tests using netbeans, but the errors in the editor were embarrassing. So I add Module1 version and packaging type to the pom.xml of Module2 and that fixed my problem (I know, it's very bad to hard code a module version, but at least, I can work without worrying about the editor list of errors)

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely too little too late, but I had this problem today with Netbeans 7.2. All jars were in place, the code was compiling from the build menu, but Netbeans was marking the files in error.

The same exact project was compiling fine with Netbeans 8.0.1.
The problem was with the "Source Root".  I clicked on menu Window -> Debugging -> Sources (Alt+Shift+8) and I noticed that I had specified sources on some of the jar dependencies of the project that were no longer valid.  Cleaning them up was a 2 step process:

1. Clean them up from the project files in nbproject dir
2. Clean them up from 
   %APPDATA%\NetBeans\7.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\java\j2seplatform\Sources.properties

After clean up, I restarted Netbeans and everything was OK.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with few jsf xhtml pages though there wasn't any error in the content of the page. So I opened each page and cut all content, saved the empty file then paste back all content and saved it. it solved the red marking error symbol for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old but for those who may be facing the same issue currently, hope this will help.
I faced the same challenge after moving my maven projects to a new directory. To fix the issue, I just simply

1. Renamed the new folder(the one containing my maven projects) just the same name as the previous folder.
2. Reimported the projects in Netbeans.